# How to take users input, modify it, then display it in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a unit converter, I will have the user enter a numeric value in a text box, select a unit type(lbs, g, oz etc...) from a select element, then do some simple multiplication to get the conversion, then finally, the part I am having trouble with, display the conversion result in a designated area. I can not get the text to change to the conversion result. I only have one conversion coded so far and that is pounds to grams, because I want to be able to display the text before I code the rest of them. Thank you and any input helps!

```
var main = function() {
  var rslt = $('#result').val;
  var num = $('#nmbr').val();
  var inpt = $('#slct1').val();
  var outpt = $('#slct2').val();
  var bttn = $('.sbs');
  $('.sbs').click(function(){
    if(inpt == 'pounds'){
      if(outpt == 'grams') {
        var pGrams = num * 453.592;
        $('#result').text(pGrams);
      }
    }
  })
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

**full code: https://jsfiddle.net/drzb6frk/**

Comment: Right, so, what exactly is the problem? Where does the code stop doing what you expect? I do see a few things that could be a problem, but without knowing what you expected it to do differently and where it stopped all I can do is assume.

Comment: `var rslt = $('#result').val;` typo. all of the vars in that function: should probably be in the click handler, otherwise they won't update when the input is changed. two if statements could/should be combined. `var bttn = $('.sbs');` is unused. variable naming is unnecessarly unclear, `var input` is just one extra character but a hell of a lot easier to read.

Comment: @KevinB you solved my problem so you answered your first question haha. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this javascript code:

```
var main = function() {
  var bttn = $('.sbs');
  $('.sbs').click(function(){
    var rslt = $('#result').val;
    var num = $('#nmbr').val();
    var inpt = $('#slct1').val();
    var outpt = $('#slct2').val();
    if(inpt == 'pounds'){
      if(outpt == 'grams') {
        var pGrams = num * 453.592;
        $('#result').text(pGrams);
      }
    }
  })
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: Thank you! I probably never would have figured that out.

Comment: No problem, glad you got it working:)